# How do I parse nested a tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

The HTML code

```
<a href="1.co">1<a href="2.co">2</a></a>
```

I tried to call BS recursively for the "contents" of the fist tag, but BS fails

```
        if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
>           markup = markup.read()
E           TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Python code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer


def parse(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, parse_only=SoupStrainer(['a']), features="html.parser")
    for tag in soup:
        if tag.name == "a" and tag.has_attr("href"):
            print(tag["href"])
        if hasattr(tag, "contents"):
            for text in tag.contents:
                parse(text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse("""<a href="2.co">2<a href="3.co">3</a></a>""")
```

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Can you a [mcve]? ([repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LastingAcidicInternet))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want ALL `<a>` tags, then as suggested, use `.find_all('a')`. But if you specifically only want the nested `<a>` tags, then you go do what you are currently doing, but then within each tag, you want to find the children with `<a>` tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer


text = '''<a href="1.co">1<a href="2.co">2</a></a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, parse_only=SoupStrainer(['a']), features="html.parser")
for tag in soup:
    if tag.name == "a" and tag.has_attr("href"):
        children = tag.findChildren('a')
        for child in children:
            print(child["href"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do find_all('a')

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<a href="1.co">1<a href="2.co">2</a></a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print(item['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Call to str() fixes the problem

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

def parse(text):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, parse_only=SoupStrainer(['a']), features="html.parser")
    for tag in soup:
        if tag.name == "a" and tag.has_attr("href"):
            print(tag["href"])
        if hasattr(tag, "contents"):
            for text in tag.contents:
                parse(str(text))  # This is where the bug was

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse("""<a href="2.co">2<a href="3.co">3</a></a>""")
```